# Javascript OR (||) with ternary operator

Tags: javascript

```
payload = {type: 3}
const type = payload.type || state.active === "period" ? 1 : 2;
// type returns 1
```

I'm surprised by the return of `type` which is 1.. I was expecting it to be 3.. What happened here? What I want to really achieve is if the type index is not available then `state.active === "period" ? 1 : 2` will be the basis of the value of type..

How to achieve this in a clean one line?

Comment: ...[order of precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). Yet again.

Comment: Not really but the answer above is perfect for me

Comment: The question is *exactly the same* - there is an OR and a conditional operator used in the same expression. Which is what you have - an OR and a conditional operator in the same expression. I fail to see how the other question differs from this one.

Answer (score 4):

You need parentheses, because of the [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

```
const type = payload.type || (state.active === "period" ? 1 : 2);
```